# Connect OpenWRT to Eduroam

Tags: router, raspberry-pi, openwrt

I have a Pi baked with OpenWRT, which I want to connect to the Eduroam network of our university. Is there a way, I can connect to Eduroam and get OpenWRT to submit the username and password so it can get access? I havent found any option for that yet...

Comment: Much easier to do with a "normal" OS.

Comment: search for `openwrt travel router captive` - you'll get some insights

Comment: @ChanganAuto I chose OpenWRT because the Pi in question is specifically gonna be used as a router and DNS server OpenWRT is much less resource intensive then "normal" OSes and has in-built features which make it extremely efficient in handling typical "router-workloads" while providing the necessary security functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [WPA Enterprise (Client)](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/wifi/basic#wpa_enterprise_client) section in the documentation. OpenWRT settings closely map to the underlying wpa_supplicant settings, so first find the correct configuration for that, then translate it into the corresponding settings in UCI. (If visiting another institution, remember that the EAP settings depend on the organization that issued you the Eduroam account, not on the one providing physical connection.)

The Wi-Fi device section is likely to look somewhat like this:

```
option eap_type 'peap'
option auth 'auth=MSCHAPV2'
option identity 'foo@example.com'
option password 'hunter2'
option ca_cert '/etc/whatever/example.com.pem'
```

I would hope that there also was an option that maps to wpa_supplicant's `domain_suffix_match`, which is needed for proper EAP certificate verification with many institutions, but the docs don't seem to mention it.

---

I would probably suggest running standard Debian instead, as then you could directly manage the WPA client (wpa_supplicant or iwd) configuration. The web UI and unified configuration system that OpenWRT has might be more of advantage in general, but in this case it's only restricting you.

(The added efficiency (if any) of OpenWRT would be more relevant when running it on a typical home router's potato-tier MIPS CPU, but a bit less relevant for a relatively powerful Pi – the wireless uplink is likely to be the bottleneck anyway.)

> search for `openwrt travel router captive` - you'll get some insights

Eduroam networks are not captive-portal networks – it was designed to use WPA-Enterprise (802.1X) authentication, and the Eduroam "Service Definition" even explicitly prohibits the use of captive-portal logins.

Comment: Thanks for that in-depth answer! I also looked at the travel router captive thing and was kinda confused about the mention of that in the context of Eduroam. I'll definitely look into using plain Debian...